# Get correct datetime object from dataframe column with random string present with date and time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have dataframe like this:

```
       id                   Time
0      N01  Thu Sep 10 11:44:30 XYZ 2020
1      V33  Thu Sep 10 11:39:05 ABC 2020
2      N01  Thu Sep 10 11:44:30 XYZ 2020
```

I am trying to convert `Time` column to datetime object. If I'm using:

```
df1['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Time'])
```

It is throwing a warning message:

```
UnknownTimezoneWarning: tzname BRT identified but not understood.  Pass `tzinfos` argument in order to correctly return a timezone-aware datetime.  In a future version, this will raise an exception.
  category=UnknownTimezoneWarning)
```

I am aware that there is a `format` argument in `pd.to_datetime()` to pass the input format. But I don't know what to pass as `format` to bypass the random strings in the middle of the `Time` column.

Is there any way to correctly get the datetime object from the `Time` column so that the random strings don't have any effect?

Comment: How are you getting these values `XYZ, ABC` in your `Time` column?

Comment: I'm just getting the df from another party. And I don't know how they are getting the values, I just need to handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you the characters you wants to remove are some following upper cases, you can handle it with a regex function with remove followed uppercase:

import pandas as pd

```
data={'id':['N01','V33','N01'],
      'time':['Thu Sep 10 11:44:30 XYZ 2020','Thu Sep 10 11:39:05 ABC 2020','Thu Sep 10 11:44:30 XYZ 2020']}


df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['time']=pd.to_datetime(df['time'].str.replace('([A-Z].[A-Z])',''),format=r'%a %b %d %H:%M:%S  %Y')
print(df)
```

result:

```
    id                time
0  N01 2020-09-10 11:44:30
1  V33 2020-09-10 11:39:05
2  N01 2020-09-10 11:44:30
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It worked like a charm. But I am just curious as to why `str.replace('([A-Z].[A-Z])','')` is not replacing 'Thu Sep' part from the time string? They are also strings, right?

Comment: It's because this regex pattern is looking for a uppercase which is followed by another uppercase. it would replace THU or SEP but not Thu or Sep